# Panning logic in Kinect WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I have been trying to get panning/zooming effects working for image in my WPF application. I have tried gesture recognition to get these panning/zooming effects. Though I am able to do that, but the gesture based system doesn't seem to be very reliable.

When comparing the same functions between gesture and tracking, the latter seems to be very reliable approach. I have been able to get the zoom effect working with tracking in my application but I am confused about the approach to adopt for panning.

I was seeing this Worldwide telescope demo enabled with Kinect, which has both panning and zooming in the demonstration. Here's the link to the same: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-tMp4WkQjA
Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

The approach I have used in the [Gesture Based Picture Viewer](https://github.com/karanjthakkar/Gesture-Based-Picture-Viewer) I worked on was: When my left is raised on the sides, I activate the `Pan` mode and then the image follows my hand movements. The finesse with which the hand motion is replicated on the image can be modified easily in the code. I hope it helps you in some way. Go through the [README](https://github.com/karanjthakkar/Gesture-Based-Picture-Viewer#gesture-based-picture-viewer) and you are good to go. Let me know if you have some doubts in the code.